# AngularJs ng-repeat expressions not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I need to add tick marks below a [ui-slider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider) so that it looks somewhat like this:

[image: slider with ticks]

**Automated interpolation with ng-repeat doesn't work:**

In my controller I have a `limits` array

```
$scope.limits = [ 1, 3, 5, 10, 15 ];
```

I reference `limits` in my html:

```
<p ng-repeat="l in limits" 
   style="left:{{$index*100/(limits.length-1)}}%"
   class="slider-tick">
    <span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span>
    <br>
    {{l}}
</p>
```

In Chrome this works fine, **but not in IE9** - all the tick marks and numbers are bunched up on the left-hand side

*Chrome:*

[image: ng-repeat works in Chrome]

*IE9:*

[image: ng-repeat breaks in IE9]

It's as if the `style` expression is not working (`"left:{{$index*100/(limits.length-1)}}%"`)

**Manual interpolation works:**

If I code the repeated elements by hand, then it works as expected in IE9.

```
<p class="slider-tick" style="left:0%"  ><span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span><br/>1</p>
<p class="slider-tick" style="left:25%" ><span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span><br/>3</p>
<p class="slider-tick" style="left:50%" ><span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span><br/>5</p>
<p class="slider-tick" style="left:75%" ><span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span><br/>10</p>
<p class="slider-tick" style="left:100%"><span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span><br/>15</p>
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to have the `ng-repeat` expression work in IE9?

**Update:**

After using the Developer Tools to inspect the DOM, I see there is no `style` tag on the `<p>` element at all.

*IE9:*

[image: IE9 DOM]

In Chrome's developer tools, that style tag does exist:

*Chrome:*

[image: Chrome DOM]

Comment: Have you tried taking that expression and sticking it inside of the `<p>`? Then you can see what it expands to in IE9, maybe it's not expanding correctly. You can probably also see what it expanded to in the dev tools.

Comment: @MattGreer - what do you mean by `inside the <p>` please? I had the `ng-repeat` on the `div` **outside** the `<p>`, that didn't work, so I moved the `ng-repeat` onto the `<p>`, as it is shown above. Neither work.

Comment: @MattGreer - I've added some screenshots of the DOM in Chrome vs IE9 - IE9 doesn't even **have** the `style` tag!

Comment: there are known issues with legacy versions of IE9 and several of the directives that need post ready compilation that angular processes using `$copmile`.  See my answer below on ways to try to support this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [ng-style directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead of the `style` attribute. The browser is trying to interpret your Angular expression as (invalid) CSS; ng-style will make Angular evaluate the value and then apply it as the `style` attribute.

```
<p ng-repeat="l in limits" 
   ng-style="{left: ($index*100/(limits.length-1)) + '%'}"
   class="slider-tick">
    <span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span>
    <br>
    {{l}}
</p>
```

Comment: Awesome - that worked - thanks! To be honest, I feel a bit lame now! :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Just be aware that there are a couple of other attributes with the same pitfall. If you see any standard attributes with an 'ng' prefix (ngHref, ngSrc, ngDisabled, etc.) then you should use those ones with Angular expressions to make sure it will work.

Answer (score 3):

IE9 struggles with several of the directives requiring the `$compile` service.  There are some steps you can take to try to enable IE9's support through shimming and such.  Angular has a section of the developer guide dedicated to IE support of angular:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

The most important piece directly related to IE9, is the `ng` namespace for the `html` tag:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
```

I have found, that though the guide says this works, it's not always the case.  Sometimes you have to use the `data-ng-repeat` as opposed to `ng-repeat`:

```
<p data-ng-repeat="l in limits" 
   style="left:{{$index*100/(limits.length-1)}}%"
   class="slider-tick">
    <span class="slider-tick-mark">|</span>
    <br>
    {{l}}
</p>
```

Edit... there was also some issues a while back where using `ng-repeat` would not transclude and bind elements on the same tag properly (your style declaration).  the fix there is to ensure you have the latest version of Angular.